# Erro ao inserir objeto no banco de dados

Tags: java-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0, ejb

Estou tentando inserir um registro aqui e não estou conseguindo. Bom, tenho uma tabela `entity` chamada `Message`, na qual essa `entity` recebe um objeto de `Categoria` e `Tipo`, ou seja, quando eu vou cadastrar, eu seleciono qual categoria desejo e também qual o tipo. Só que na hora de inserir está dando pau, gera a exceção exposta abaixo. No banco está tudo pra gerar auto incremento, e não sei porque ele persiste nesse erro.

Minha Entity `Message` :

```
public class Message extends AbstractEntity {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "TB_MESSAGE_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "SQ_TB_MESSAGE", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "TB_MESSAGE_ID_GENERATOR")
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
@Column(name = "ds_name")
private String name;

@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "bl_removed")
private String removed;

@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "ut_registration_instant")
@Convert(converter = LocalDateTimePersistenceConverter.class)
private LocalDateTime registrationInstant;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_user")
private User user;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_category")
private Category category;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_type")
private Type type;


public Message() {
}

@PrePersist
public void updateCreateDate() {
    setRegistrationInstant(LocalDateTime.now());
}

public Message(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Message(Integer id, String name, String removed, LocalDateTime registrationInstant, User user, Category category, Type type) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.removed = removed;
    this.registrationInstant = registrationInstant;
    this.user = user;
    this.category = category;
    this.type = type;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getRemoved() {
    return removed;
}

public void setRemoved(String removed) {
    this.removed = removed;
}

public LocalDateTime getRegistrationInstant() {
    return registrationInstant;
}

public void setRegistrationInstant(LocalDateTime registrationInstant) {
    this.registrationInstant = registrationInstant;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public Category getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public Type getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(Type type) {
    this.type = type;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Message)) {
        return false;
    }
    Message other = (Message) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "com.vztech.pmv.business.entity.Message[ id=" + id + " ]";
}

}
```

A exceção que ocorre segue abaixo:

> ```
> Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): 
> org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
> Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_tb_category"
>   Detalhe: Key (id)=(1) already exists.
> Error Code: 0
> Call: INSERT INTO tb_category (id, ds_name) VALUES (?, ?)
>     bind => [2 parameters bound]
> Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.vztech.pmv.business.entity.Category[ id=1 ])
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.processExceptionForCommError(DatabaseAccessor.java:1611)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:898)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:962)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:631)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2002)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:298)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:377)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:165)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:180)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:489)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:301)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:798)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1737)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:226)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:193)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:138)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4207)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1441)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1531)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3168)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:352)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:158)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(JTASynchronizationListener.java:68)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:452)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:854)
>     at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:719)
>     at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
>     at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4566)
>     at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2074)
>     at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2044)
>     at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
>     at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy295.save(Unknown Source)
>     at com.vztech.pmv.business.facade.__EJB31_Generated__MessageFacade__Intf____Bean__.save(Unknown Source)
>     at com.vztech.pmv.view.MB.MessageBean.insert(MessageBean.java:106)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>     at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
>     at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
>     at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
>     at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
>     at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
>     at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
>     at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>     at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>     at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
>     at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_tb_category"
>   Detalhe: Key (id)=(1) already exists.
>     at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2161)
>     at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1890)
>     at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
>     at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:559)
>     at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
>     at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:363)
>     at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:125)
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:890)
>     ... 94 more
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Usa isso em vez de uma sequence:

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

Ele ta tentando inserir novamente a categoria como os mesmo ID,e implementa o Seriazable no classe e melhor usar as anotações do que AbstractEntity  :

@Entity
   @Table(name="nomedatabela",schema="nomedoesquemasetiver")